# warning in tcp connection in matlab

Tags: matlab, tcp

I'm try to connect matlab with streaming by tcp connection, the problem is tcp connection are mis too much data from streaming. I want to read 47 integers at one time, thats the reason why I add the loop to wait until `BytesAvailableFcnCount` has value larger than 47*4 (assume integer is 4 byte), also the matlab give me the following warning: 
 `Warning: Unexpected Warning: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached` 
 here is the code:

```
`function data = get_data()
t = tcpip('127.0.0.1', 5000);
t.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte' ;
t.BytesAvailableFcnCount =47*4 ; 
fopen(t) ;
t.Timeout = 20 ;
while (t.BytesAvailableFcn < 47*4)
     end
    data = fscanf(t, '%d', 47);
    dlmwrite('test.dat',data);
x = 1 ;
while (x ==1)  
 while (t.BytesAvailableFcn <47*4)
     end
    data = fscanf(t, '%d', 47)
 end

`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up `BytesAvailableFcn` and `BytesAvailable`. `BytesAvailableFcn` is a callback function to be set by you, `BytesAvailable` returns the number of available bytes.